# Converting from ArcGIS layout into Google Earth as kmz with legend?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, kml, legend, kmz

How to display an ArcGIS legend in kmz or kml file?

I am trying to do so in conversion tool of ArcGIS but while exporting it to Google Earth it is not showing the legend.

Answer (score 1):

You do not specify which ArcGIS for Desktop tool or version you tried to use to do the conversion.

However, legend creation is discussed in the help page entitled [Creating KML in ArcGIS for Desktop](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s200000009000000) where it says:

> A legend is the only screen overlay that you can include in your KML
>   created in ArcGIS for Desktop. Legends added in the map document
>   layout view will be included as a KML screen overlay and a button
>   folder that allows you to change where the legend will be displayed on
>   the screen. Legend overlays will only be included in the KML when
>   using the [Map To KML](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00120000004p000000) tool.

If you are not using the [Map To KML](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00120000004p000000) tool, then I recommend trying that.

I tested it just now using ArcGIS 10.2.2 for Desktop and it worked.

---

I just re-tested this at ArcGIS 10.4.1 for Desktop and, as expected, it still works.  One thing to be careful of is that although Google Earth turns on the Legend item, it defaults the position that you want to see it to be `None`.  To see the legend you must change that radio button to the position you want the legend displayed in (see red "arrow" in the picture below).

[image]

For interest I tried opening the same `*.kmz` in ArcGIS Earth, and with respect to the legend inside it, that behaved identically to Google Earth.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you modify inserted legend   in layout view, (convert to graphics), this is a reason not to display map legend in google earth!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if anyone else has had the same issue, but when converting map to kml (to include a legend), the legend doesn't actually fully convert. I was able to get the color patches, but not the descriptions. 
[image]

So, I added a placemark where I wanted the legend to appear in Google Earth, added a png of the legend grabbed from ArcMap, using the "Add Custom Icon" button of the Legend. I increased the size, moved the point into my data folder, and voila, there it is.
[image]