# Adding map legend displayed on Google Earth?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, kml, google-earth, legend

My colleague sent me an `*kml` file with a map legend and said it was exported from AgLeader software. I am using ArcGIS to convert my shapefiles into `*kml` files and I've tried both "layer to kml" and "map to kml" conversion but still can't add a legend.

More detailed description: I added a legend to layout and saved my layers as a map document `*mxd`, ran "map to kml" converstion and output a `*kmz` file but it still doesn't show me the legend.

I am using ArcGIS 10.4 for Desktop.

Does anyone know how to do this?

[image]

Comment: What version of ArcGIS for Desktop are you using?

Comment: I'm using 10.4.

Comment: I've updated my answer on the duplicate.  I suspect that what you may be missing is that although Google Earth turns on the Legend item, it does not turn on the position you want the legend displayed in and so you must choose one of the options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that your colleague sent you a `*.kmz` rather than a `*.kml`, and that if you unzipped that `*.kmz` you would find not just a `*.kml` but also an image that is your legend.

To add that legend into your ArcMap layout you could Insert | Picture.

Conversely, to convert your ArcMap legend into one for Google Earth you could use something like Windows' Snipping Tool to grab it as an image for you to place in a Google Earth folder that you save as a `*.kmz`, or the procedure described in [Converting from ArcGIS layout into Google Earth as kmz with legend?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/121510/converting-from-arcgis-layout-into-google-earth-as-kmz-with-legend)

Comment: I am not so sure about that. It is a `*.kml` file that he sent me.

Comment: As far as know a KML does not include an image.  Have you used a text editor to look inside the KML file?  If it is not ASCII then maybe he has renamed a *.kmz to *.kml and neither Google Earth nor ArcGIS for Desktop care that this was done.

Comment: Ok, now I run "map to kml" converstion and output a `*kmz` file but it still doesn't show me the legend, why? @PolyGeo

Comment: Please edit your question to revise it with this, and a more detailed description of your precise steps to achieve this new result.

Comment: Question edited. @PolyGeo